# codeigniter use concat regex in where clause

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I have a custom query like this

```
SELECT `wo_number`,`request_date`,`wo_type`,`requestor` 
FROM `work_orders` 
WHERE CONCAT(",", `assigned_to_enggs`, ",") REGEXP ",(21),"
```

It works fine for me I want to use it in Codeigniter Active Record. I have tried something like

```
$this->db->select('wo_number,request_date,wo_type,requestor')
->from('work_orders')
->where("CONCAT(',', assigned_to_enggs, ',') REGEXP ',(21),'");
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong in syntax. can someone guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below case in where and use result() for get result array

```
$this->db->select('wo_number,request_date,wo_type,requestor');
$this->db->where("CONCAT(',', assigned_to_enggs, ',') REGEXP ',(21),'", NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->select->from('work_orders');    
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
```

If not work than you also write query like below in codeigniter.

```
$query = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
$query->result()
```

Comment: thanks it worked.. 
BTW `find_in_set()` method is another way of doing it
`->where("find_in_set($get_engineer_id, wo.`assigned_to_enggs`)");`